# Calling function on changing combobox options in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

In the below code, how can I call the `OptionCallBack` function on `cm` changes and pass the selected option into the message box to be displayed?

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

app = Tk()
app.configure(background='DimGray')
app.geometry('600x600')
app.resizable(width=False, height=False)

def OptionCallBack():
   tkMessageBox.showinfo( "Selected Phase", "??????")



variable = StringVar(app)
variable.set("Select From List")

cm = ttk.Combobox(app, textvariable=variable)
cm.config(values =('Select From Phase A', 'Select From Phase B'))
cm.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a trace on the variable:

```
def OptionCallBack(*args):
   tkMessageBox.showinfo( "Selected Phase", variable.get())

variable = StringVar(app)
variable.set("Select From List")
variable.trace('w', OptionCallBack)
```